# When did Dr. Carolyn Trainer start calling herself Lady Octopus?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, doctor-octopus

Dr. Carolyn Trainer, Dr. Octavius' prodigy, first appeared in *Amazing Spider-Man #405*.

But I can't find a reference for the issue where she takes on her own name — Lady Octopus. I've checked her [fandom page](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Carolyn_Trainer_(Earth-616)). It just says,

> She later reappeared as Lady Octopus, sporting her own set of cybernetic tentacles.

Which comic book issue is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first issue where she was shown sporting tentacles was *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #406](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_406)* (October, 1995). At that time though, she called herself 'Dr. Octopus', as the original Doc Ock was dead, and she is indeed a doctor in her own right.

[image: Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #406, page 9]

The earliest issue I can find where she's referred to as 'Lady Octopus' is *[Secret War #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_War_Vol_1_3)* (October, 2004). This name isn't mentioned within any of the story pages though, only on a back-up page naming all the villains who appeared on the final story page of the issue.

[image: Secret War #3, page 34]

The earliest issue I can find where she calls herself 'Lady Octopus' is *[New Avengers Vol. 1 #63](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_Avengers_Vol_1_63)* (May, 2010).

[image: New Avengers Vol. 1 #63, page 14]